# What does `GiftedChat.append` from react-native-gifted-chat do?

Tags: react-native, react-native-gifted-chat

In the documentation it does not talk about the method `append`. What does it do exactly?

Here is an example on how its usage is suggested by the documentation.

```js
setMessages(previousArr => GiftedChat.append(previousArr, message));
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Luckily, we can check the [source code of GiftedChat](https://github.com/FaridSafi/react-native-gifted-chat/blob/master/src/GiftedChat.tsx):

```js
static append<TMessage extends IMessage>(
    currentMessages: TMessage[] = [],
    messages: TMessage[],
    inverted = true,
  ) {
    if (!Array.isArray(messages)) {
      messages = [messages]
    }
    return inverted
      ? messages.concat(currentMessages)
      : currentMessages.concat(messages)
  }
```

It appears that the function does what its name suggests. It *appends* `messages` to `currentMessages` by using [concat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat). Since the default value for `inverted` is set to `true`, it adds `messages` to the end of `currentMessages`, thus `messages` are supposed to have `a newer timestamp` than `currentMessages`. We would expect this to happen from a chat application.

Its usage is straight forward and actually documented in the [official example on their GitHub page](https://github.com/FaridSafi/react-native-gifted-chat).

Here is the necessary snippet.

```js
const onSend = useCallback((messages = []) => {
    setMessages(previousMessages => GiftedChat.append(previousMessages, messages))
  }, [])

  return (
    <GiftedChat
      messages={messages}
      onSend={messages => onSend(messages)}
      user={{
        _id: 1,
      }}
    />
  )
```

`GiftedChat` manages an internal array of messages. In order to provide an API to your application, i.e. to allow you to manage messages in your own states, it returns the full message array after appending new messages.

Comment: Do you know why are they using useCallback hook? and also without dependencies

Comment: The useCallback hooke makes the `onSend` function stable. Its dependency array is empty because the function does not use any variable. Thus, the function needs to be created only once on mount. Technically, it will work without using useCallback, however the function will then be recreated on each rerender. Most likely, onSend would be recreated on every message change if it wouldnt be a callback, since `messages` is a state which triggers a rerender on every change.